# PHP Regex how to capture floating point numbers that do not have a letter at the end

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_match_all and I want to capture the floating point numbers that do not have a letter following them.

For example

```
-20.4a 110b 139 31c 10.4
```

Desired

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 139
        [1] => 10.4
    )
```

I've tried was able do to the opposite using this pattern:

> /\d+(.\d+)?(?=[a-z])/i

which captures the numbers with letters that [you can see in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/35).  But I can't figure out how to capture the numbers that have no trailing letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with a positive lookahead:

```
[+-]?\b\d*\.?\d+(?=\h|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/38)

`(?=\h|$)` asserts presence of a horizontal white space or end of line after matched number.

**Alternatively** you can use this regex with a possessive quantifier:

```
[+-]?\b\d*\.?\d++(?![.a-zA-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/39)

Answer (score 2):

Use **negative** lookahead:

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?(?![a-z])/i
```

But it is not sufficient, you have to exclude also digit and dot:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![a-z\d.])/i
```

**PHP:**

```
$string = '-20.4a 110b 139 31c 10.4';
preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![a-z\d.])/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 139
            [1] => 10.4
        )

)
```

Comment: This matches `20` out of `20.4a`,which is not what OP wants - DVed

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches one can take here.

Atomic group matching and a negative lookahead or word boundary:

```
(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?![a-z])
(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

Using a negative lookahead that also denies a dot and numbers:

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![a-z.\d])`

Positive lookahead to a space (seems to be the separator in here) or the end of string

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s|$)`